# ASOP Automotive build stuck on boot, complaining about package_native

Tags: android, android-build, android-automotive

I'm trying to run an build ASOP (with automotiv/car related packages included) on a ARM64 device. I've already managed to build and run Android 11 on the device without the car parts. Building and starting the device with the car parts included works fine, but it get stuck on booting (while showing the boot animation). Essentially the problem seem to be that iorapd fails (and then retries to connect) to the package manager. The tombstone left behind is filled with the following

```
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 1970-01-01 00:06:10+0000
pid: 252, tid: 252, name: iorapd  >>> /system/bin/iorapd <<<
uid: 1071
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'Fail to create version map in 60000 milliseconds. Reason: Failed to connect to package manager service. Is system_server down?'

--------- log system
01-01 00:00:06.704   252   252 I iorapd  : iorapd (the prefetchening) firing up
01-01 00:00:06.744   252   252 E iorapd  : SQLite error (14): cannot open file at line 38589 of [b2325a6e1c]
01-01 00:00:06.744   252   252 E iorapd  : SQLite error (14): os_unix.c:38589: (2) open(/data/misc/iorapd/sqlite.db) - 
01-01 00:00:08.490   252   252 I iorapd  : Reinitialized database at '/data/misc/iorapd/sqlite.db'
01-01 00:00:08.491   252   252 W iorapd  : Reconnect to package manager service: 1 times
01-01 00:00:13.566   252   252 E iorapd  : Cannot get package manager service!
01-01 00:00:14.567   252   252 W iorapd  : Reconnect to package manager service: 2 times
01-01 00:00:19.598   252   252 E iorapd  : Cannot get package manager service!
01-01 00:00:20.598   252   252 W iorapd  : Reconnect to package manager service: 3 times
...
01-01 00:06:03.508   252   252 E iorapd  : Cannot get package manager service!
01-01 00:06:04.508   252   252 W iorapd  : Reconnect to package manager service: 60 times
01-01 00:06:09.540   252   252 E iorapd  : Cannot get package manager service!
01-01 00:06:10.541   252   252 F iorapd  : package_manager_remote.cc:118] Fail to create version map in 60000 milliseconds. Reason: Failed to connect to package manager service. Is system_server down?
--------- log main
01-01 00:02:25.885   252   252 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
01-01 00:02:25.986   252   252 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
01-01 00:02:26.187   252   252 I ServiceManager: Waiting for service 'package_native' on '/dev/binder'...
01-01 00:02:26.288   252   252 W ServiceManager: Service package_native didn't start. Returning NULL
```

The build (mk) file is to a large extent common between the non-car version (that works) and the car version (that doesn't) - both inherit `product/core_64_bit_only.mk` and adds all device specific configuration.

The difference is that the non-car build inherits `device/google/atv/products/atv_base.mk` while the car build inherits `packages/services/Car/car_product/build/car.mk`.

Two things that would be greatly appreciated

1. Any pointers to why this would happen and how to mitigate it
2. Any instructions on how to make all the logs persisted (so I can analyse if anything else goes wrong during the boot), I've tried to add a custom init.log.rc to vendor/etc/init/hw with bellow, but it doesn't seem to make logcat actually persist the logs

```
on post-fs-data
    exec -- touch /data/bootchart/enabled
    setprop logd.logpersistd.enable true
    setprop logd.logpersistd persist
    setprop persist.logd.logpersistd "logcatd"
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?